# How to minimise the size of action menu items in Android 3.2?

Tags: android

I am developing a simple four-action app for Android 3.2. I want all the menu items to appear in the action menu on a single line. (At the moment they appear as a 2x2 grid. I want a 1x4 grid.)

To achieve this I would like to:

- remove the text and display only the icon

  - I have tried removing the `android:title` attribute, but the empty space for the text remains
- minimise the width of the items, so that they all fit in one row (this may not apply to literally all screen sizes, but in my case I can see that the icon images **could** fit on my emulator screen)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've tried playing around with the `android:showAsAction` attribute, but Eclipse won't compile, and reports `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just a guess , but it seems like a thing that android won't support out of the box , since there are many different screens out there , and some won't have enough space for all your buttons (you have 4 , but imagine someone who wishes 10 instead) and google won't like it that the user will be frustrated when trying to click the tiny action buttons.

if you want, you can always create your own customized action bar , which would have any behavior you wish .

Comment: hmmm... but if I add one or two more buttons, the buttons still take up two rows, the widths are adjusted accordingly, therefore four buttons should be able to fit on one row?

Comment: if you make your own action bar , you are the one responsible for the rules of the layout . it all depends on what you do there . for the normal action bar , however , it depends on the screen resolution and density , since if there is not enough room , some of the action items will go to the overflow button .